# Getting actual value from cummulative value in talend

Tags: mongodb, talend

How to get the actual value from the cumulative value in talend? for example 
a car runs for 1000 km. next day the car will start from 1001 km. what i need is how to calculate the total kilometers covered on a particular day

```
1000 km on 27-10-2017
2000 km on 28-10-2017
```

the total kilometers covered on 28-10-2017 is 1000 km. how to do that in talend?  need to update around 100 000 history records in mongodb

Comment: This question shows no effort into attempting a solution first. StackOverflow is no code production service. First you should always start with the business rules which seem to be messed up here. Total kms covered on 28 "is 1000kms" - I don't see why since in the list it says 2000 kms on 28 alone. Second not everybody knows what a lakh is. Also this could possibly be done just in MongoDB with the correct statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the temp variable to store the previous value of "km"

**Input ---> tSortRow(based on dates) ---> tJavaRow(save previous value) ---> output**

in tJavaRow use the below code:

output_row.km = input_row.km-context.temp;

output_row.date = input_row.date;

context.temp = input_row.km;

define a context variable "temp" and put a default value as 0.

Hope this help